# django.security.csrf: Forbidden (Origin checking failed - https://sentry.domain.com does not match any trusted origins.)

Tags: sentry, django-csrf, apache-sentry

> django.security.csrf: Forbidden (Origin checking failed -
> https://sentry-domain.com does not match any trusted origins.)

I installed self-hosted-master sentry from https://github.com/getsentry/self-hosted based on documentation on: https://theappsguy.dev/setting-up-sentry-self-hosted

I configured it for SSL with changing:

`nginx/nginc.conf`:

- from `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https; (instead $shema);`
- to `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https; (instead https);`

`sentry/sentry.conf.py`:

- uncomment: `SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')`

`.env`: `SENTRY_USE_SSL=1`

`sentry/config.yml`:

- uncommnet: `system.url-prefix: 'https://<IP>'`

and I configure a proxy above this configuration on OS to forward traffic toward server name

I can see GUI of sentry with https://sentry.domain.com
but when it comes to login (correct or wrong username and password)
I see the below error:
and in logfile this error appears:

> django.security.csrf: Forbidden (Origin checking failed -
> https://sentry-domain.com does not match any trusted origins.):
> /account/recover/ (status_code=403 request=<WSGIRequest: POST
> '/account/recover/'>)

Answer (score 1):

It is solved by some steps
at first based on documentation I set up environmet before start installing

I removed those configuration

then I change config.yml and changed system.url-prefix: 'https:/IP' to system.url-prefix: 'https:/sentry.domain.com'

stop containers
then reload daemon
restart docker
start containers